# microsoft graph tutorial leaves gap and now stuck using python and API calls

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been reading up on MS graph and using python to query it.

I followed this guide which I found a little tricky to follow. I can't see where they're getting the libraries from, e.g. if I want to do something different, its not obvious to be which libraries I would pick and why. I've done a good bit of searching and can't find a catalog/dictionary/wiki that explains these libraries. In addition the last bit felt like a bit half baked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python-app-only?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=5

It gives links to review to build your own graph queries, but the links provide examples, none of which are in python, even though the tutorial is in python.

My ask...

1. where can I go to learn about the different libraries, so I can pick alternative ones
2. how do I query ms graph which the approach of the tutorial?
3. (more spoon fed) - I am trying to use an app-only account, which is registered in azure, approved, and a public hotmail account has granted it the permissions/scope I'm looking for. I would like the app-only to query the hotmail accounts' calendar and read appointments.

i didnt try much as im a little lost what i do next. to find the info, i followed the tutorial, i read lots of microsoft pages and other knowledgebases. I have tried to play with the code in the tutorial, but im quite stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)The Python installation and libraries and the latest versions are available here: https://pypi.org/project/python-msgraph/

2)Here are the few sample MS graph queries using the python with examples:

*)To get user:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=4

*)To Send Mail:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tutorial-step=6&tabs=aad

*)Fetch a User's Events from a given Calendar
Now let's fetch the Event instances from the main calendar of johndoe:

```
calendar_lookup = dict()
for calendar in johndoe_calendars:
    calendar_lookup[calendar.name] = calendar

primary_calendar = calendar_lookup['Calendar']
johndoe_events = calendar.Event.get(johndoe_instance, calendar=primary_calendar)
```

3)For app-only authentication to the application. This is required to obtain the necessary OAuth access token to call the Microsoft Graph. In this step you will integrate the Azure Identity client library for Python into the application and configure authentication for the Microsoft Graph SDK for Python (preview):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python-app-only?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is very helpful, but im still struggling. I can acquire an access token, but not sure if its correct. For the app-only app, I request a token with the app's client_id and client_secret value (not id), and the tenant the app resides within. I am trying to access the calendar of a public account (e.g. hotmail), one that does not reside within the same tenant. To work backwards, I have since granted admin consent to the app within azure. I have also granted consent from the user. Scope include user.read + calendars.read but i call .default for scope. Still receive Access denied to all users

Comment: i resolved the issue with being able to access users within the same tenant. Although within azure it said user.read was granted to the tenant, checking the token i could see this permission was missing. I granted consent again, and then it started to work. The issue remaining is, the public account cannot be found (Authorization_RequestDenied) using email. I have also changed my token tenant from the ID to 'common' without luck. Using email (Authorization_IdentityNotFound) and id (ErrorInvalidUser).